# How should I wash my MTB knee pads?

Tags: maintenance, cleaning, pads

I have a pair of 7iDP Transition knee pads that are starting to smell and are in need of a wash. However, I am not totally sure the best course of action for cleaning the pads. Please let me know your suggestions or how you clean your knee pads.

Answer (score 4):

Read the manufacturer's suggestions first.

Then I'd just chuck it all in the washing machine and run a normal cycle.

If there's mud, I'd hose it all off when I wash the bike down before putting in the washing machine.

---

Once clean, line dry them.  A hot-air dryer does more damage to your clothes than anything else.

Comment: I suspect drying them is a bigger risk of damage - Unless manufacturer instructions say otherwise, do not put them in a dryer to dry, hang them up to air dry.

Comment: @mattnz good point - I've got a hot air dryer and its main function is to hold up my toolbox in the garage.  I've used it twice in two decades to dry something.

Comment: For kit that's been stinky for a while, or has ground-in mud, a soak in (cold) water with some biological detergent added can help a lot.  For the main wash you might want a sports-specific detergent intended for destinking.  I'd use the "hand wash" (obviously not literally true) or "synthetics" cycle rather than "cottons", which will have a rather vigorous spin that might stress the padding for no benefit

Answer (score 3):

Washing them by hand with some active detergent should always be the safest, but putting them in the washing machine at low temperatures and low spin rates never harmed my pads.

Maybe you could add some disinfectant or antibacterial additives to compensate for the low temperatures. And if you have a spare bag, e.g. from a full face helmet, those can be used to keep the washing machine from ripping holes in the thin, stretchy fabric of some pads. But thats not a big issue usually. Avoid high temperatures while drying.

This answer feels more like an addition to @Criggie. Would have commented, but I'm lacking reputation.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, this is definitely an answer in it's own right rather than a comment.  Hand washing and antibacterial detergent are both good ideas.

Comment: Nope this is a great standalone answer by itself, and covers new points I missed like low spin rate.  Keep up the good answers !